# SQL linq convert string to int

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a varchar timestamp column

```
id | filename | timestamp
-------------------------------
1  | example  | 20150226145109
```

Now I need a query which only shows me the entries where the timestamp is older than 7 days.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
string past = date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Unfortunately, I can't do this now in my linq:

```
var requests = from request in db.Request
               where Convert.ToInt32(Timestamp) < Convert.ToInt32(past)) 
               select request;
```

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression."

I don't know how I can fix this.

In an earlier version I executed raw sql like this:

```
SELECT filename, timestamp FROM dbo.Requests WHERE timestamp < 20150219060814
```

Can anyone tell me how I am able to convert the strings to ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your column is `varchar` type and it stores the dates in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` pattern you can use simple string comparison *(instead of converting it to int)*. Like:

```
var requests = from request in db.Request
               where db.Timestamp.CompareTo(past) < 0
               select request;
```

Consider the following sample SQL statement.

```
SELECT  1 
where'20150226145109' > '20140226145109'
```

It will give you `1` back since "string" `'20150226145109'` is greater than `'20140226145109'` *(one year older date)*.

Although you should store `DateTime` in its respective column type, but one of the advantages of your current `DateTime` format is that it works based on **natural string sorting** rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't even parse this cause of this: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' to 'string'.

Comment: @FRules, my bad, Use `CompareTo` like `where db.Timestamp.CompareTo(past) > 0` , I mixed the C# code with SQL.

Comment: Thanks! I think it worked! In my case I had to use "<" instead of ">" though.

Comment: @FRules, oh yes. Just saw your comparison.